# Cycle-intersecting subsets

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. We call $D\subseteq V$ *cycle-intersecting* if for every [simple cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) $C\subseteq V$ we have $C\cap D \neq \emptyset$.

Is there a graph $G$ such that for every cycle-intersecting subset $D$ and for every simple cycle $C$ we have $|C\cap D| > 1$?

Comment: What if $D$ is a single vertex?

Comment: Such a set is usually called a _feedback vertex set:_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. And this is not about cycles at all.

Take minimal cycle-intersecting subset. If it has at least two vertices from any cycle, remove any vertex from it and get a smaller cycle-intersecting subset.